# How to enable pynput to monitor keyboard in another program

Tags: python, pynput

I am using pynput to monitor keyboard to simplify some actions. It works well when the program is focused, but will not response when lost focused.

Is there any other config that should be add, so that I can trigger the listener when I am focused on another program like word or excel or full-screen game?

```
class UserListener(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        print('start listening...')

        def on_press(key):
            if key == Key.home:
                print('key home is pressed')
            elif key == Key.esc:
                return False

        with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
            listener.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lsner = UserListener()
    lsner.start()
```

=====================================================================

Update 1:

The program above can run normally. However it do not work when DNF(a game I played) gets focused.

Comment: *but will not response when lost focused.*,Do you mean that it won't ``print("key home is pressed")`` when lost focused?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Actually, I open the cmd and type `python main.py`. It print 'start listening...'. Meanwhile it will print 'key home is pressed' when I tap the Home. But if I switch to another program, it will not print 'key home is pressed' or stop whenever I tap the Home or ESC, just like the program stops when it lost focus

Comment: I can run your code normally no matter whether the cmd window lost focus.